# Piccaso Image not Loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Image is Not loading ,when i was using Picaaso and Glide, And its give URL Path, when i was running the app. I also Attached the pHoto of Image which having error. I tried Everything,Even i used Glide library also.But Image was not loading and its give the app error.ALso there is no error in **LOGCAT**.Please help , i m new in this.

[App Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ctXF.png)

**Master Fragment**

```
        public void initData(String authorization) {


             ApiInterface apiInterface = 
          ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<MasterEventResponse>> call = 
             apiInterface.getAllDetail("Token " 
                    + authorization);
         call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MasterEventResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MasterEventResponse>> call, 
              Response<List<MasterEventResponse>> response) {

               Log.d(" MasterResponse", response.toString());
                   if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                List<MasterEventResponse> masterResponse = response.body();


                MasterEventResponse mMasterEventResponse;
                for (int i = 0; i < masterResponse.size(); i++) {
                    String time = masterResponse.get(i).getStartTime();
                    Integer duration = 
                  masterResponse.get(i).getEventDuration();
                    String topic = masterResponse.get(i).getTopic();
                    String name = masterResponse.get(i).getMasterName();
                    String image = masterResponse.get(i).getEventImage();
                    Integer id = masterResponse.get(i).getId();

                    mMasterEventResponse = new MasterEventResponse(id, 
              time, duration, topic, name, image);

                    masterEventResponse.add(mMasterEventResponse);
                  
                masterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something is crash.", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }


        
}
}
```

**MasterAdapter**

```
                  public class MasterAdapter extends 
          RecyclerView.Adapter<MasterAdapter.ViewHolder> {





@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTime.setText(masterEventResponse.get(position).getStartTime());
    holder.mDuration.setText(Integer.toString(masterEventResponse.get(position).getEventDuration()));
    holder.mDescription.setText(masterEventResponse.get(position).getTopic());
    holder.mMentor.setText(masterEventResponse.get(position).getMasterName());


   String url = masterEventResponse.get(position).getEventImage();


                 Picasso.get()
                .load(url)
                .resize(50, 50)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
                .into(holder.mImage);

        

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
       return masterEventResponse.size();
      //return ();
}

      public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTime;
        public TextView mDuration;
       public TextView mDescription;
       public TextView mMentor;
       public ImageView mImage;
   // public LinearLayout mStatus;


    public ViewHolder(@NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        mDuration= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);
        mMentor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mentorName);
        mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_master);


    }
}
```

}

**MOdel Class**

```
         Integer id, String masterName, Integer eventDuration, 
            String topic, String eventImage, String startTime) {
           
       }
```

**XML File**

```
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#BACCD1"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#BACCD1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="2dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_master"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/decor"/>

                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="#BACCD1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="10:45AM"
                            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                           />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_detail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Train your mind and get richer.."
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" />



                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_mentorName"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Sadhna Gupta"
                                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" />



                        </LinearLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_status"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img_corps"
                                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_corporate"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_corps"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Corporate"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/lnl_restaurant"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_join">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_join"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Join"
                                    android:textColor="#845247"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnl_favorite"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40 min"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You have an error and you are not telling us which error.

Comment: You posted much too much code. Plese reduce to a minimum to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @blackapps-The app error i also tag,please check.

Comment: I see nothing. You should mention the error you get.

Comment: @blackapps - the image URL path https:// staging.png,its all over in my app.Image is not loading instead  https://image1.jpg" ,this coming..in my app.

Comment: That does not look like a valid url. And your link is invalid too. I still have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: [App Image Error][1] - This one Above Master Fragment .There you get the image of my  issue, what i actually want to convey

Comment: I see an image and some texts are messing up. Is that what you wanna say? Why should we guess? Tell first how it should look like.

Comment: @blackapps-yes,that mess up text is my issue.Shared the Image also... [App should look like this] <- above Master Fragment. Where i shared image.Please look.Thanks

Comment: So there are several errors. The wrong image. But i see an image. Where does it come from? And texts messed up. Are they the right texts?

Comment: @blackapps- text and everything in xml i already set it, this issue coming after connecting through webservice.i just wanna know. is there issue with code, or server side. because i havn't get any error from logcat.

Comment: If all comes from xml then why dont you show that xml? My god.. i have to pull everything out of you.

Comment: i just wrote, everything which intially needed.Share the XML file also.

Comment: Again too much to look at. I give up.